# Handle Select().CopyToDatatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Is there any way to handle this method to not crash if there is no results.
Lets say i have something like this

```
  Dim _dtTemp As New DataTable
  _dtTemp = dtMain.Select("Nivo = 0").CopyToDataTable

     If _dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       For Each row In _dtTemp.Rows
         ....
       Next
     End If
```

Every time when dtMain dont have results to query it crash and say's something like `There is no rows ....` and my app crash. How to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this all on one line. Just assign the return value to the array of DataRow, test if you have some rows and finally call the CopyToDataTable

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = dtMain.Select("Nivo = 0")
if rows.Length > 0 Then
    Dim newTable = rows.CopyToDataTable()
    ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Where does it crashes exactly? I would put a few breakpoints to find this out first.
If at the If statement, just write the condition:

```
If _dtTemp.Rows.Count == 0 Then
' nothing
elseIf _dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0 Then
'and carry on
```

Comment: No mate it Crash on .Select method with error 'The source contains no DataRows.' . I know it doesnt have results but why it cant just copy empty datatable